# SQL Case Statement with SELECT inside INNER JOIN. Error of multi-part could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, join, case

I am writing an `INNER JOIN` that added fields like CompanyId etc..

But in my `CASE` inside the `INNER JOIN` I am getting an error after the `WHERE`

The error say on the IR.MyId and ICB1.MyId

> "multi-part identifier could not be bound"

My intention for this query is to add a `CASE` inside the `INNER JOIN`.

So the first column is `A.CompanyId`. The second column will be the `CASE` statement to check if the ID exists in another table. If not, it will do another `SELECT` statement, ELSE just `MyID`.

But I get an error on the `SELECT COUNT(*)` inside the `CASE WHEN`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         A.CompanyId, 
         CASE 
            WHEN (SELECT count(*) 
                  FROM Table1 IBC1 
                  WHERE IR.MyId = ICB1.MyId) == 0
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
         END 
     FROM 
         cmp.CompanyNews A) E ON NP.CompanyId = E.CompanyId
```

Comment: `case when (SELECT count(*) FROM Table1 IBC1 WHERE IR.MyId = ICB1.MyId ) == 0` replace `==` with `=`

Comment: try adding and identifier for your case: `THEN 1 else 0 END as NameOfIdentifier`

Comment: @John please provide the full query, also add the tag for the RDBMS you are using (sql-server, oracle, ...)

Comment: Where's no such an alias as IR

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your full query, but if it's viable I'd take the following approach to this:

```
...
    CASE
        WHEN ICB1_ID.ID IS NULL
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END [ColumnName]
FROM
    ...
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT A.CompanyId
            FROM cmp.CompanyNews A
        ) E
    ON NP.CompanyId =  E.CompanyId
    OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 ICB1.MyID ID
            FROM Table1 IBC1
            WHERE ICB1.MyId = IR.MyId
        ) ICB1_ID
```